# CORS issue with Azure AD OpenID Connect logout in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, openid, azure-active-directory

I have a tenant in Azure which hosts a number of apps.  I'm using OpenID Connect for authorization.  In the login.microsoft.com openid-configuration, an `end_session_endpoint` URL is supplied.  [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-a-sign-out-request) article explains how to send a sign-out request.  This will end the session in Azure, but not on my client (an Angular2 SPA).  To do this, I'm using [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) and the following code:

```
this.http.get('https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/logout",')
    .toPromise()
    .then(function () { 
        this.oauthService.logOut();
    }
);
```

The GET to login.microsoftonline.com will end the session on the server and the `logOut()` call will end the session locally.  When I run this, I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/logout. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:51518' is therefore not allowed access.

When I check the response from the login.microsoftonline.com GET, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not one of the response headers.  I'm very surprised it wouldn't have that header with `*` as the value.  In any event, how can I address this?  I see there is a CORS setting in App Services and I added my localhost (testing locally currently) to CORS for one of the apps in the tenant, but it's still not working.

Temporarily, I've added an API endpoint on my apps API that makes a call in C# to the login.microsoftonline.com URL, but it's annoying to have to do that.  I'd like to do it all through javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect the browser to the URL. You can't call it over AJAX.

> You must also redirect the user to the end_session_endpoint for sign-out.

Azure AD does not allow cross-domain calls on the login endpoints, and you can't change that.

You can redirect the user to:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/ccb87602-82bf-4f35-b7d2-aa‌​aaaaaaaaaa/oauth2/lo‌​gout?post_logout_red‌​irect_uri=https%3a%2‌​f%2fsitename.azurewe‌​bsites.net%2fHome%2f‌​SignedOut
```

The `post_logout_redirect_uri` parameter allows you to specify where the user's browser should be redirected after log out. This way the user won't lose context. Do make sure to save up the user's work on your app's side before redirecting so you don't get angry users.

Comment: The wording I read in the document was "You **can** simply redirect the user to the end_session_endpoint", implying that that's one option.  When you redirect to the endpoint, it indeed ends your session, but it loses the context of what tenant/app you were using.  So if a user was logging out or if you were explicitly ending a user's session (eg. b/c of inactivity), the only way to get back to the app (which would, of course, require reauthentication) would be to manually enter in the app's URL.  This is a really poor user experience.

Comment: You can specify a post logout redirect URI in the parameters. Then the user will be redirected back to your app after sign out.

Comment: Here is an example URL: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/ccb87602-82bf-4f35-b7d2-aaaaaaaaaaaa/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fsitename.azurewebsites.net%2fHome%2fSignedOut`.

Comment: I somehow missed that.  I'm able to get what I need now.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, you still can kinda lose context, you need to handle stuff on your app's side before redirecting so the user doesn't lose work possibly :)